# web2py multiple form

Tags: python, sqlite, web2py

i created a multiple form

```
form = SQLFORM.factury(db.table1,db.table2)
```

`db.table2` has the following fields, the field `invoice_id` is linked to `db.table1` and a `catalogue_id` is linked to another table `db.table0`

```
db.define_table('table2',
    Field('id','id'),
    Field('user_id', db.auth_user, default=auth.user_id, writable=False,readable=False,
          label=T('User Id')),
    Field('invoice_id', db.table1,  writable=False,readable=False,
          label=T('Invoice')), 
    Field('catalogue_id', db.table0,
          label=T('Catalogue')),
    format='%(thiscatalogue)s',
    migrate=settings.migrate)
```

after the form is sent the `invoice_id` should be automatically filled from web2py and getting the `ID` of the `sent` data

but having this

```
Field('invoice_id', db.table1, ... )
```

make the field must have a value before it submited

Comment: What is the `sent` data? Where should the "invoice_id" come from?

Comment: `invoice_id` is the `id` of the new inserted record in `db.table1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/7#One-form-for-multiple-tables). In this case, something like:

```
form = SQLFORM.factory(db.table1, db.table2)
if form.process().accepted:
    invoice_id = db.table.insert(**db.table1._filter_fields(form.vars))
    form.vars.invoice_id = invoice_id
    db.table2.insert(**db.table2._filter_fields(form.vars))
```

First insert the new invoice into table1, which returns the id of the new record. Then, before inserting into table2, set form.vars.invoice_id to the id of the new invoice record.

Comment: thanks
is there something like `SQLFORM.factory`, to use it instead of `crud.read()` ?

Comment: Are you saying you want a readonly form based on related records from two separate tables? Haven't tried it, but I think you could do `SQLFORM.factory(db.table1, db.table2, record=myrecord, readonly=True)`. You would have to create the "myrecord" object so it contains all the fields in both tables.